# How to send javascript array to php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I've tried a lots of solution from so, but no one worked for me.
So I have a javascript array and i should pass it to `php` for upload it into `mysql`.

This code is in a `php` page, where is an editable grid. If press enter in the grid it creates a new row, with the value of the editeble cell and this value goes into the `var val=[]`and this should go into `mysql` via `php.

I've tried two kind of pass from so as you can see below

Code I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var dbs=0;
    var val=[];
    function myFunction(e) {
            if(e.keyCode == 13){
                var newId = (new Date()).valueOf();
                var value=gridbox.cells(1,0).getValue();
                gridbox.addRow(newId,value);                
                val.push(value);
                gridbox.cells(1,0).setValue('');
                gridbox.editCell(1,0);
                dbs=dbs+1;

            }
    }
    function upload(){
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(val);
             /*$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "upload.php",
                data: {'data' : jsonString}, 
                cache: false,

                success: function(){
                    alert("OK");

                }
            });*/
        var jsonData = $.ajax({
                  url: "upload.php",
                  data: { 'data' : val},
                  dataType:"json", 
                      async: false
                  }).responseText;
        }
</script>
```

**UPLOAD.PHP**

And it creates new empty row in the db, so it runs, but the $data is empty

```
//$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_GET['data']));
$data=$_GET['data'];

  // here i would like use foreach:
/*
  foreach($data as $d){
     echo $d;
  }*/


$db_irattar = new indotekDbConnection("irattar");


for($i=0;$i<4;++$i){
$sql="INSERT INTO akt_hely(Tipus,Megnevezes) 
VALUES('2','$data[$i]')

";
}

$db_irattar->Execute($sql);
$db_irattar->Close();
unset($db_irattar);
?>
```

[Network monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJ6IP.jpg)

Comment: Did you look at the value of `val` in your browser? (using `console.log(val)`) Or looking at what's sent by monitoring network? What browser do you use?

Comment: Yep, it has datas in it.

Comment: How big is it? There's a limit on the size of the URL parametes, so it would probably be better to use `POST` instead of `GET`.

Comment: Use [network monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) which is built-in to Firefox. Look if the data is indeed sent as query parameters.

Comment: It is not work neither with post.

Comment: What should i check in network monitor? ( Added a picture)

Comment: You can see that `upload.php` is not requested with something like `?data=123` behind it, so you might conclude that there is something wrong with the Javascript code. However, try to inspect it some more, because I do not have Firefox myself.

Comment: Any idea whats wrong with it?

Comment: When you change to `type: "POST"`, you have to use `$_POST['data']` to get the parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that you are assigning `var jsonString = JSON.stringify(val);` and sending `val` in ajax.

try

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
              url: "upload.php",
              data: { 'data' : jsonString},
              dataType:"json", 
                  async: false
              }).responseText;
```

Instead of

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
              url: "upload.php",
              data: { 'data' : val},
              dataType:"json", 
                  async: false
              }).responseText;
```

And decode the json string in php like `$data=json_decode($_GET['data']);`

Comment: It seems to be better, now in the network monitor I have upload.php?data=["a',"\nb"], but stil an empty rows get into mysql. What should i have in the upload.php?

Comment: I think the val[] can be longert than the maximum size of the url. But it is not work with $_POST.... Can you help me,

Comment: If he sends `jsonString`, he needs to use `json_decode($_GET['data'])` in PHP.